# Access object javascript console

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, object

I am facing an issue by trying to loop through arrays/objects.
When I loop through the set of arrays, showed by the screendump, it just output blank results. But when I console.log the data I am trying to loop through, it shows up like the screendump below. The main problem is that I can't loop through the data for some reason.

**Edit: systems variable, is containing the output of the objects/array**

I have tried this, but that output blank:

```
$.each(systems, function(index, value){
    console.log(value);
})
```

[image]

Comment: Why can't you iterate through data ?

Comment: The bottom of text can be extracted, if you're concerned!

Comment: Hover over the `[i]` icon to find out.

Comment: "Value below was evaluated just now" is the notification

Comment: Exactly. While `{}` (the first line) is what the value looked like when it was logged.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` is usually used to print simple strings.

When you want to examine more complex objects, such as arrays, HTML elements, objects etc, you should use `console.info`:

```
console.info(systems);
```

This will allow you to browse through the array, expand its sub-elements and examine it in a clearer way.

See this snippet for an example, and consider your browser's dev console will probably show it much better:

```js
var systems = ['mac', 'windows', 'linux', 'ios'];
console.info(systems);
```

Here's how it looks in Google Chrome's dev console:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your `systems` variable is not empty. You can iterate data with for loop:

```
for (let k in systems) {
    console.log("k = ");
    console.log(systems[k]);
}
```

Comment: It's very weird. The system variable aint empty, it contains the output in the screendump, but when I loop with your code, It outputs blank.